# Weird Redirect/rewrite URL causing 404 issue

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect, 404

I am having this weird issue where if I go to any page,

e.g. if I go to a category page, http://wonderna.com/all-products/daily-health/sub-health.html

Contact us page or any other non-category page will have this broken URL
http://wonderna.com/all-products/daily-health/contacts

As you can see "all-products/daily-health" being append to the contacts.

Similarly if I go to customer account page

http://wonderna.com/customer/account/

Then contacts page will be rewrite to http://wonderna.com/customer/account/contacts

There is "customer/account" being append to the contacts page.

Anyone has ever experienced this issue? I am using bitnami's out of box 1.9.2.0 installation (LAMP) + mango theme from themeforest.

Comment: Hi.
Could not understand correctly.

http://wonderna.com/customer/account/login/ - Works fine for me

http://wonderna.com/all-products/daily-health/sub-health.html - Works fine for me

Although there is wrong links in footer section.

If accessed directly - http://wonderna.com/contacts - works fine

Comment: If you visit http://wonderna.com/customer/account/ first, then from this page you browse to contacts page via top menu-> Last item (on the right drop box) ->Contact Us Test, you will see the URL is being rewrite to http://wonderna.com/customer/account/contacts

Answer (score 2):

Look at the HTML source:

```
<li class="menu-item " style="list-style: none;"><a class="level2" href="contacts"><span>联系我们</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-item " style="list-style: none;"><a class="level2" href="shipping"><span>邮寄配送</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-item " style="list-style: none;"><a class="level2" href="refund"><span>产品退换</span></a></li>
```

The problem is `href="contacts"`. This probably comes from a static block, then it should be edited as:

```
href="{{base url='contacts'}}"
```

Or if it is in a PHTML template file:

```
href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>contacts"
```

To be honest, if this is really an out of the box installation with this theme, this speaks for very low quality of the theme.

Comment: href="{{store url='contacts'}}" works for me.